# Люди — человек

Tags: лингвистика

Почему в русском языке во множественном числе "люди", а в единственном — "человек"? Почему у первого слова нет единственного числа, а у второго — множественного?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос хороший, но с "почему" его лучше не начинать. Как и всегда, когда дело касается каких-то частных языковых фактов. Так уж сложилось. Можно бы еще спросить "как такое произошло?", это из области исторической грамматики. Если в двух словах, какое-то время существовали оба слова, потом "человек" стало обозначать одного человека или нескольких **по отдельности**, а "люди" - как собирательное. Последнее не имело счетной формы и формы единственного числа просто "за ненадобностью", ибо само по себе уже обозначало группу. Зато множественное "люди" постепенно вытеснило "человеки".

Хотя форма "человеки" не такая уж невозможная. Мы же спокойно говорим "десять человек" как воспоминание о тех временах, когда люди было исключительно собирательным, свойство образовывать счетную форму у "люди" так и не развилось.

Comment: Интересно посмотреть, у существительных какого типа (смысла) наблюдается супплетивизм? Например, этим свойством обладает слово "дети", потому что один "деть" - ребенок. В английском что-то похожее: children вместо childs, правда, здесь корень общий. 
Есть ли аналогия распространенности супплетивизма в других языках?

Comment: По семантике - не скажу, но обычно это слова самого древнего происхождения. В (пра)индоевропейском супплетивизм был, видимо, обычным делом. Или другое объяснение - с тех пор сблизились значения изначально разных корней, что и привело к вытеснению отдельных форм супплетивом.

Answer (score 0):

Такая штука имеет название *супплетивизм* ([ссылочка на Педивикию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)). Он есть в разных языках мира, потому что так сложилось исторически, хотя таких слов не очень много. Человек - люди, есть - быть, он - его и т.п.

Comment: Умное слово "супплетивизм" ничего не объясняет. 
Вопрос-то в том, как он тут возник.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что так исторически сложилось.

Но хотелось бы обратить внимание, что в русском языке существует слово `люд`. При этом оно хоть и собирательное, но все равно используется как существительное ед. числа. Ср.: "деловые люди", "деловой люд".

Comment: Слово "люд" есть, только оно вряд ли собирательное и уж соверденно точно не является единственным к "люди". Люди возможно только от "людь". Сравните нелюдь - нелюди.